# Count frequency of specific numbers in a text file of scientific notations

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk, grep, perl

**Background**

I have a text file, named `blood_conc.txt` as shown:

```
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.32006590271e-05, 1.990014992001e-05, 1.504668143682e-05, 2.176900659261e-06,
    7.673488970859e-06, 2.169217049562e-05, 4.343183585883e-05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    2.143804950099e-05, 0, 0, 1.849919603625e-06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.123812986073e-07, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0001365177, 7.81009e-06, 2.695291e-07, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.1799e-05, 1.82574e-05, 1.68109e-05, 2.722782e-05,
    5.355517e-05, 8.196468e-05, 7.177729e-05, 7.863765e-05, 5.774439e-05,
    1.329413e-08, 0, 0, 0, 4.320018e-06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0.0003335425, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.061237e-05, 6.36887e-05,
    2.250928e-05, 0, 0, 7.327124e-07, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
```

I would like to count number of **0** between line 3 to line 8 inclusively. i.e.

```
2.143804950099e-05, 0, 0, 1.849919603625e-06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.123812986073e-07, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0001365177, 7.81009e-06, 2.695291e-07, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0,
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.1799e-05, 1.82574e-05, 1.68109e-05, 2.722782e-05,
    5.355517e-05, 8.196468e-05, 7.177729e-05, 7.863765e-05, 5.774439e-05,
```

and the frequency of **0** should be 54.

I want a simple command line to finish two tasks:

**Task 1**: Count number of **0** in the text from Line 3 to Line 8.

**Task 2**: Count number of values lying between the interval,says , (2.452555e-05, 0.0032784).

---

**My thought**

I have do some searching in the webs and posts. I find `awk` and `grep -c` may help.

To focus the range of lines, I guess I can use `awk 'NR==3, NR==8' blood_conc.txt`.

However, I do not know how to proceed by using `grep` or `perl`. I want a simple command line which just return me the frequency.

Comment: As described what you're seeking is the data associated with histograms.  As such, if perl is your tool of choice then consider: http://search.cpan.org/~dougwebb/Statistics-Histogram-0.2/lib/Statistics/Histogram.pm    ...always beware of floating points and, for instance, making assumptions about all zeros being "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this with `awk`:

```
awk -F"," 'NR == 3, NR == 8 { for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { if ($i == 0) { cnt++; } if ($i >= 2.452555e-05 && $i <= 0.0032784) { cnt1++; } } } END { print cnt, cnt1; }' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Your starting point is good; now you have to iterate over the fields, where a precondition is to define an appropriate field separator. To count the zeroes:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS="[, ]+" }
  NR==3, NR==8 { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i==0) c++ }
  END { print c }
'
```

For checking a range change the `if` condition accordingly, something like: `if ($i >= ... && $i <= ...)`.

Comment: Thanks Janis. I appreciate your help and your explanation is clear enough to let me know the concept of the use of the control-statements.